# replacing tt italic with tt slanted at LaTeX level?

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I have a personal dislike of the CM typewriter italic design. (Sorry,
DEK :). It's fine for what it is, but I just find it distractingly fancy.) For TUGboat, I always want to replace it with typewriter slanted.

My question is, is there a way to do such a fundamental substitution at
the LaTeX level? (I don't want to distribute different
.fd files for TUGboat. That would be much too error-prone for authors, aside from
being generally crazy. :)

Trivial example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textit{\texttt{Italic typewriter that I want to be slanted.}}
\end{document}
```

For this tiny case, it's obviously no problem to replace \textit with
\textsl in the TeX source. But in practice there are plenty of times
when it is not so simple, because the \textit, or \emph, or whatever, is buried inside macros, the result of running BibTeX or other subprograms, etc.

Many packages (e.g., listings) have their own configuration methods that can suffice. I just wondered if there was a way to do it globally. It would save me a lot of time and effort. --thanks, karl.

Comment: Thank you both very much. If I could accept both answers, I would have. Randomly picked David's :). Thanks again.

Comment: See Frank's comment on mine;-) (and egreg's)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ohh egreg a bit quicker but mine's more readable:-)

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% or OT1 or TU...
%FMi {\ttfamily}% force fd to load 
\LoadFontDefinitionFile{\f@encoding}{cmtt}% force fd to load 
\DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{cmtt}{m}{it}
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/sl}{}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\textit{\texttt{Italic typewriter that I want to be slanted.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of forcing the loading manually, there is also a proper interface to it in NFSS: \LoadFontDefinitionFile{<encoding>}{<family>}

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I thought there was but memory and search foo failed me:-) I'll fix

Comment: LaTeX Companion third edition page I-747  :-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach oddly, emacs led me instead to latex.ltx line 8634:-)

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you load the font description file and then change the relevant definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Load <enc>cmtt.fd
\LoadFontDefinitionFile{\encodingdefault}{cmtt}
% replace it with sl
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{\encodingdefault/cmtt/m/it}{<->ssub*cmtt/m/sl}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\textit{test italic=slanted}}

\texttt{test upright}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of forcing the loading manually, there is also a proper interface to it in NFSS: \LoadFontDefinitionFile{<encoding>}{<family>}

Comment: @FrankMittelbach We always learn new things!